# having problem with visual studio installation

Tags: visual-studio, locked

i am trying to install visual studio but having problem with it, it says : (
unable to install the files to target location. error: the folder C:/program files(x86)/microsoft visual studio/installer of file within it is locked by another program. close any applications that might be using it and try again )

can someone help me please :(

Answer (score 0):

i have finally found a solution, i have disabled windows anti virus and now it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).